# need help for arraylist for storing the data

Tags: java, dataset

i need to store a DatSet value into ArrayList

```
while(result.next())
{
  String Adress= result.getString(1);
  String Name = result.getstring(2);
}
```

now the loop executes and i want to store the value of loop in the array list so can anybody please  help me on this i am new to arraylist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
class Person
{
    String address;
    String name;
    public Person(String name, String address)
    {
         this.name = name;
         this.address = address;
    }
}

...

List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

while(result.next())
{
  String Adress= result.getString(1);
  String Name = result.getstring(2);
  persons.add(new Person(Name, Address));
}
```

You must create a class to hold the row data, then add the objects of that class to an ArrayList.s

Comment: thanks very much. suppose i want to use that arraylist value and show it in my table in design view... how i can use the stored value of arraylist and retrieve it.. just give me the hint

Comment: @Dinup : Well... just add the corresponding getters in the Person class, and use them to fill your table view.

Comment: @Dinup: StackOverflow is generally not a site where people write code for you.  I gave you an example, but it's up to you to use that to learn more and solve your own problems.  You can use Google to search for "java getter setter" to find examples.